# Javafx modifying "Label" in SwingUtilities.invokeLater

Tags: java, javafx, pane, swingutilities

I wanted to do the following:

1. click a button
2. colors a rectangle red
3. waits 1 sec
4. colors a rectangle blue

In the following code:

---

```
GraphicsContext gc;
Button myButton = new Button("Button!");
myButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event){
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    gc.setFill(Color.RED);
                    gc.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                    gc.setFill(Color.BLUE);
                    gc.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

This works fine. It creates a red box at 0,0 with width & height of 100. But when I try to modify say, a Label, it crashes.

---

```
GraphicsContext gc;
Pane root = new Pane();
Button myButton = new Button("Button!");
Label myLabel = new Label("HELLO!"); // added
root.getChildren.add(myLabel);
myButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event){
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    gc.setFill(Color.RED);
                    gc.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                    gc.setFill(Color.BLUE);
                    gc.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
                    myLabel.setText("WORLD!"); // modified here
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

The result I'm expecting is,

1. click a button
2. colors a rectangle red
3. waits 1 sec
4. colors a rectangle blue
5. then changes the label text from HELLO! to WORLD!

But I'm getting an error. Why is this happening? Can I not modify any Pane elements in SwingUtilities?

Any advice will be helpful.

---

**EDIT**

This is the error I get when I press the button

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = AWT-EventQueue-0
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:229)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:423)
at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Parent.java:367)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.setAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:113)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.setAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:108)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.updateChildren(LabeledSkinBase.java:575)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.handleControlPropertyChanged(LabeledSkinBase.java:204)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabelSkin.handleControlPropertyChanged(LabelSkin.java:49)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase.lambda$registerChangeListener$61(BehaviorSkinBase.java:197)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler$1.changed(MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler.java:55)
at javafx.beans.value.WeakChangeListener.changed(WeakChangeListener.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(StringPropertyBase.java:103)
at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.markInvalid(StringPropertyBase.java:110)
at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:144)
at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:49)
at javafx.beans.property.StringProperty.setValue(StringProperty.java:65)
at javafx.scene.control.Labeled.setText(Labeled.java:145)
at Lego$1$1.run(Lego.java:63)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: You say "it crashes". How?

Comment: Can you post compilable example?

Comment: Callback for ```invokeLater``` executes code on UI thread, you shouldn't block it.

Comment: There is no compile time error, but when I press that button I get this error. I edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because any `Java FX components` must be managed by the `JavaFX Application Thread` due to the fact that they are not thread-safe (this is for the exact same reason that any `Swing components` must be managed by the `AWT event dispatching Thread`), so you need to modify your label indirectly using `Platform.runLater(runnable)` as next:

With Java 8

```
Platform.runLater(() -> myLabel.setText("WORLD!"));
```

With previous versions of Java

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            myLabel.setText("WORLD!"); 
        }
    }
);
```

We use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(runnable)` to make the `AWT event dispatching thread` execute some code that will modify `Swing components` at some unspecified time in the future, it is the same idea with `Platform.runLater(runnable)` in case of `Java FX components`.

**NB:**  Use only `Swing` components or only `Java FX` components, avoid mixing `Swing` and `JavaFX` components unless you have no other choices.

Comment: You are the man. That makes sense. I'm fairly new to GUI with java, so I was very confused between javafx and swing and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

**Never pause JFXAT, dont sleep on it** , you kill responsiveness , create a thread , sleep on it , and then inside of it use  Platform.runLater to update UI.

```
updateLbl(){
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
         Thread.sleep();//sleep //try catch
         Platform.runLater ... //inside update ui
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: I think I get what you're saying. If I have multiple buttons that both draw something, and if I run one of them with sleep, it pauses any other GUI updates (but still updates like texts and printf stuff). Is there a way for me to only pause that specific graphics?

Comment: As i sayd , never! Put JFXAT to sleep ,  create another thread that you make sleep instead , and on that thread you call runLater (after your sleep) to update UI , that way you dont pause your UI/JFXAT thread and action is delayed .

Comment: I got it to work with creating a new thread. But then I assume every time I want to sleep, I need to make a new thread inside of newly created thread? Say I want to pause one more time, can I just sleep in that thread again (I assume this one is correct) or do I make a new thread inside of that thread?

Comment: Feel free to keep it alive as long as you need it , once you dont need it it  will get garbage collected , so if you wanna sleep one more time and update it to something else just put another sleep after your runLater and then use RunLater again to do another update .So you will -wait,update,-wait,update,There is no need to  make another thread within that thread what purpose that would have?You only need that one thread to escape from JFXAT, if your method is called on JFXAT, just remember dont put that sleep() into RunLater, or on method that is invoked from JFXAT

Comment: Thank you! Lastly, what does AT stands for in JFXAT?